# select randomly a attribute from a table where count field of the row have lowest value

Tags: java, sql, ms-access-2007

a table loadcount have two attributes did and count.i need to select did where the count is lowest. for example if:

```
 did        count
 657        0
 698        1
```

then 657 has to be returned. similary if two rows have same count value and both are lowest then one of them needs to be selected at random.plzz help me.My academic project submission deadline is very near and i couldnt figure it on my own.Plzz provide me with codes,sql query.I am using microsoft access and java for the project.

Comment: What you have tried ?If you facing any errors update it here , hands are here to support you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the MIN function to find the lowest one

```
SELECT MIN(expression)
FROM tables
WHERE predicates
```

so in this case it would be

```
SELECT MIN(count) as "Lowest Count"
FROM tableName
```

to select a random cell from the MIN info returned , it depends on what you are using MySQl, PostgreSQL, etc...

Select a random row with MySQL:

```
SELECT MIN(count) as "Lowest Count"
FROM tableName
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Select a random row with PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT MIN(count) as "Lowest Count"
FROM tableName
ORDER BY RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

Select a random row with Microsoft SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 MIN(count) as "Lowest Count"
FROM tableName
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Select a random row with IBM DB2

```
SELECT MIN(count), RAND() as "Lowest Count"
FROM tableName 
ORDER BY IDX FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Select a random record with Oracle:

```
SELECT MIN(count)
( SELECT MIN(count)
FROM tableName
ORDER BY dbms_random.value )
WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: Thnks a lot..I kind of achieved what i wanted to using your help..My query looks like this                                                                    "select top 1  Did,TeleCount from TeleLoad  where TeleCount=(select  min(TeleCount) as 'Lowest Count' from TeleLoad ) and Category=? order by rnd(rnd(Did)) "      Now i need to increment the TeleCount field by one in row whose Did has been choosen.Is there a way to do this in same query.I can achieve it by writing separate update query and again thnks for your help..

Comment: give this a look... http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/an-access-query-that-returns-every-nth-record/3617... it explains what you want to do